# Problem with hotspot - WiFi connection on, but internet is down

Tags: connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, internet

I often connect my laptop (U20.04) via Android hotspot (Redmi Note 10 5G).

Systematically, after a while, internet connection on my laptop disappears. In particular, the indicator shows that there is still a wifi connection with my phone, but internet is not available.

Two solutions:

1. Turn off and turn on wifi on my laptop- After this, internet connection comes back
2. Turn off and turn on the hotspot on my phone. After this, internet connection comes back

Anyway, in both case, after a while the internet connection disappears again.

I've tried my laptop with other networks (also with other hotspot), but the problem is not present.

Is there some way for fixing this? Is these some way for performing a diagnostic test?

Please ask if additional information are required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I have a fix for LinuxMint which is derrived from Ubuntu and I posted the fix on LM.

Using "Search" (application), I searched for ".conf" in "File System" and found the file
/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

This .conf file contains:

[connection]

wifi.powersave = 3

(and I changed it to 0 (zero), but you should set it to 2)

After I posted the above, someone added the below on-line.

### Changing it to 2 is disable, 3 is enable, 0 is default value, 1 is don't touch existing setting.

From https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=231490

Comment: Thanks a lot. Going to try this Solution and I'll let you know

Comment: I've tried your solution for several days. Unfortunately, the problem has not been solved. As I said in the question, I don't lose the wifi connection, but I lose the internet connection. Anyway, +1 for the attempt and for the kindness!

Comment: During boot, if I turn off "quiet splash", I see rfkill being started. I haven't studied "man rfkill" but it might be good to know.

Comment: (Not sure this is really how it works...) When I set up routers, I set the "lease time" to remember connected devices for a week (or more). If your router refreshes connections and your PC is down at the time, it may expect you to reconnect when brought back up.

Comment: The file contents in the instructions actually has separate lines... with a line break between [connection] and wifi.powersave = 2 (the line break is lost in these comments)

Comment: You might try an earlier (older) kernel at boot. If you have any other wifi modules (assuming you collect PCs) you might try changing it.

Comment: Regarding your comment on "lease time", I want you to remember that my router is an Android Smart phone... and I'm not able to set up "lease time" like in a standard router... or maybe there is a way to set it, but I'm not aware about!

Comment: Going to try the proposed solution with a newline between [connection] and wifi.powersave=2. Anyway, if there is some hints on lease time is welcome for me!

Comment: Last minute thought (rapidly running out of ideas); As I read hotspot/tethering it indicates it allows you to provide internet THROUGH YOUR MOBILE DATA CONNECTION. You might try either wifi or Bluetooth connection to your PC. Keep your phone in a location with good cell tower exposure (good cell signal, not in your pocket or holster) and will likely work well. Walk around house and find best signal, then leave it there. You might make yourself a developer and enable Mobile data always active (if it isn't already).

Comment: In Developer mode, you can set your phone so it doesn't turn off while it is plugged in to a power supply. Plugging it in and leaving it on may also help. Keep your phone from doing other tasks maybe. Perhaps starting the phone in Safe mode, might keep other activities from interrupting your connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jim. I've tried these solutions today, but they do not work. I've noticed that the connection gets lost whenever I receive a Whatsapp message, or an email, or any internet operation that I don't directly control.

Comment: One last thought. In Developer mode, you can set an option to effectively turn off all apps that are not actively open. If you close Whatsap, no notices, if you close Gmail, no notices. So only have hotspot running and close all others. When you want Whatsap, leave it running and all others that you want to be operational like Gmail. Try enabling, Background process limit, select, No background processes (or At most 1 process). Also try Don't keep activities. Try them individually and perhaps in combination. I have not used these, but maybe they will work for your needs.

Comment: Perhaps look them up before using them. At least in Safe Mode, any apps added to your device won't function like Whatsap. You could turn off notifications in Gmail, and only see your email when you open Gmail.

Comment: In Development mode, there is another switch, Tethering hardware acceleration. Perhaps tethering your PC to your phone might improve your situation by bypassing the radios and going hardwire.